How does homotopy theory simplify topology but allow for complexity in higher category theory?
I'm trying to understand the dual nature of homotopy theory, which seems to play different roles in algebraic topology and higher category theory.
In algebraic topology:

Homotopy theory is often seen as a way to simplify the study of topological spaces by focusing on invariants that ignore fine details, such as homotopy groups. This approach highlights large-scale properties and invariants under continuous deformation, potentially at the expense of more granular structure.

It seems that homotopy theory imposes constraints on topological spaces by ignoring certain details, thereby making the analysis more tractable by simplifying the kinds of spaces and maps considered.


In higher category theory:

Conversely, in the context of higher category theory, homotopy theory appears to introduce a different kind of complexity. Higher categories involve morphisms between morphisms and so on, up to n-levels or infinitely many levels. This can lead to rich and intricate structures not seen in ordinary categories.

The use of homotopy equivalence instead of strict isomorphisms in higher categories allows for more nuanced relationships and structures that would not be captured by simple categorical equivalence.


So I am wondering, how can homotopy theory both simplify structures in algebraic topology and facilitate complexity in higher category theory? Or am I wrong and homotopy theory simplifies and ignores fine details even in higher category theory?

Because homotopy theory enhances set theory

“Conversely, in the context of higher category theory, homotopy theory appears to introduce a different kind of complexity.”: Homotopy theory eliminates a lot of complexity from the more traditional algebraic definitions of higher categories.  Plenty of higher category constructions have been performed only in the framework of homotopy theory, simply because the know nonhomotopic definitions would require too much effort.  For example, higher categories of bordisms.

@DmitriPavlov So homotopy theory also omits finer details in context of higher category theory meaning that finer grained non homotopy framework of studying higher categories would uncover more detail?

@Exitpath This is what I am struggling with. Is it enhancing set theory in sense of uncovering deeper finer grained truths, or is it coarser grained approach that helps us uncover the higher category realm which would be harder/not possible using finer grained non-homotopy based framework?

@PanMrož: It omits the irrelevant auxiliary technical machinery based on the traditional algebraic framework and replaces it with the much more efficient machinery of homotopy theory.  There are no “finer details” omitted or uncovered, since the relevant definitions are equivalent.  This is similar to how in algebraic geometry Weil foundations were replaced with the more efficient Grothendieck foundations.

I'm not sure this is an apples-to-apples comparison. On one hand you are observing that some questions about topological spaces can be reduced to questions about underlying homotopy types and many spaces present the same homotopy type. On the other hand, you're noting that category theory can be enhanced by homotopy theory to produce the strictly more general theory of $(\infty,1)$-categories and doing this results in new and interesting objects.

@PanMrož One could always work with categories enriched over some nice category of topological spaces, and work up to homeomorphism instead of homotopy. However, I think homeomorphism is too strict of a notion for most applications people have in mind. For example, categories of spectra are supposed to be related to cohomology theories and those are often homotopy invariant. Additionally, one would like to recover derived categories as truncations of certain infinity categories, and necessarily a notion of homotopy enters the picture here again. It just depends on what you want to do

In some ways everything in mathematics can be used both to simplify things and make them more complex. Say the notion of a group simplifies things because you can notice that some set you are dealing with forms a group and then you can use general facts about groups proved by simple algebraic manipulations to prove things without more cumbersome arguments with explicit descriptions of elements of the set, but the notion of group also lets you define nuanced relationships and structures that would be hard to define without it.

@Exitpath What do you mean by 'set theory'?

@JamesEHanson I just mean roughly that the category of sets is a full subcategory of infinity groupoids

@Exitpath I see. I guess I feel like this isn't a great way to phrase the idea given that a lot of what goes on in the field of set theory doesn't really fit that cleanly into just thinking about the category of sets (e.g., inner model theory).

@JamesEHanson Fair enough. I didn’t mean to be reductive, just that higher category theory allows for Hom-spaces that have homotopy groups in degrees $>0$

I think one way to look at this is to say that, from a certain point of view, topological spaces are far more complicated than categories and homotopy types are somewhere in the middle. The only wrinkle is the question of whether or not your "morphisms" are invertible. So the relationship between homotopy theory, as it is used in algebraic topology, and homotopy theory as a category theoretic paradigm, is not completely straightforward. I tend to think of things as something like the following picture, in which < is supposed to indicate "is less complicated than."

